# Sort / limit order on simple db query

Tags: nosql, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm wondering about how a query like the following will work....

```
select * from survey where Year < '2000' order by Year desc limit 1
```

My question is, does the limit apply:

1. After the records are sorted, in which case I'll definitely get the last record before the year 2000. or...
2. Before the records are sorted, in which case a single record will be picked from natural order & then not sorted at all (since there's only one record).

This seems somewhat obvious but Amazons documentation doesn't seem to cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems somewhat obvious but Amazons documentation doesn't seem to
>   cover it.

Yo, still the answer is definitely 1), otherwise the `limit` clause wouldn't be useful for any real world scenarios at all (see below); in addition it would severely violate the [Principle of least suprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_surprise), insofar the [Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) syntax is modeled after SQL, which works as expected in this regard, see e.g. the [LIMIT clause in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT):

> When using LIMIT, it is a good idea to use an ORDER BY clause that
>   constrains the result rows into a unique order. Otherwise you will get
>   an unpredictable subset of the query's rows — [...].

For example, otherwise *SimpleDB* wouldn't allow proper pagination, which is orchestrated via `limit` indeed (see Mocky's answer for details on [How to do paging with simpledb?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832779/45773)), i.e. you'll receive a *next token* in case there are more results, which wouldn't yield correctly sorted pages, if `limit`wouldn't obey `order by`.

Accordingly, to finally provide some reasoning deduced from Amazon's documentation, [Count](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/CountingDataSelect.html) hints towards the expected behavior as well:

> The next token returned by count(*) and select are interchangeable as
>   long as the where and order by clauses match.