# How to retrieve more than 100 Records from Amazon Simple DB

Tags: c#, amazon-simpledb

I am Creating an application in MVC and using Amazon cloud service for backend. I need the Data in Bulk from Database like so I am using the Query like this-

```
  SelectResponse response = simpleDBClient.Select(new SelectRequest()
  {
      SelectExpression =  "select * from survey1 limit 2400"

  });
```

which is now working fine and returning 2400 Records. Now I want to Apply Search on these Records So I must have to use where clause but when I am using where clause then its returning only 10 Records in any Valid Condition.

Please Help me Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: See whether this answer helps :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832779/2959100

Answer (score 2):

You can use `limit` with the `where` clause. For more detail here is the `Syntax` for the `Select` `Query`-

```
select output_list from domain_name [where expression] [sort_instructions] [limit limit]
```

The `output_list` can be: *, `itemName()`,count(*), list of attributes

1. * for all attributes.
2. `itemName()` for the item name only.
3. count(*) for the total count of items matches the query expression. It will return the number of items in a result set instead of returning the items.
4. An explicit list of attributes (attribute1,..., attributeN)

The domain_name is the `domain` from which you want to search `items`.

The expression is the `match expression` for items. You can use select expressions like =, <=, <, > =, like, not like, between, is null, is not null etc.

The `sort_instructions` sorts the results on a single attribute, in an ascending or descending order.

The `limit` is the maximum number of results to return (default: 100, max. 2500).

Please Note-

> The total size of the response cannot exceed 1 MB. Amazon SimpleDB
>   automatically adjusts the number of items returned per page to enforce
>   this limit. For example, even if you ask to retrieve 2500 items, but
>   each individual item is 10 KB in size, the system returns 100 items
>   and an appropriate next token so you can get the next page of results.
>
> Note: Operations that run longer than 5 seconds return a time-out
>   error response or a partial or empty result set. Partial and empty
>   result sets contain a NextToken value, which allows you to continue
>   the operation from where it left off.

[Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_Select.html)

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDB can only retrieve only 1MB of data at a time, SimpleDB puts a nextToken in response to indicate that there is more data to be retrieved.

Here is how do it in Java.

```
public List<Item> getItems(){
    AmazonSimpleDBClient client = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(...);
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    String nextToken = null;

    do {
        final SelectRequest request = new SelectRequest();
        request.setSelectExpression("MY SELECT QUERY");

        // SimpleDB can paginate the result. For paginated result NextToken value will be not null
        request.setNextToken(nextToken);
        nextToken = null;

        SelectResult result = client.select(request);

        if (result != null) {
            nextToken = (result.getNextToken() != null) ? result.getNextToken() : null;
            items.addAll(result.getItems());
        }
    } while (nextToken != null);

    return items;
}
```